# SQL Server JDBC returns many result set when a stored procedure invoked

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

By default SQL Server JDBC driver returns result set of all SELECT query executed in a stored procedure. I have to call CallableStatement.getMoreResults() and close all of them. I do not want any result set as return value when executing SQL Server stored procedurel; are there any ways to prevent returning result set when executing SQL Server stored procedure?

Comment: So you are calling a stored procedure that executes multiple SELECT queries, but you don't want the results? Are there other side effects of the stored procedure? Just trying to understand the problem a bit better.

Comment: no other side effect other than updating a few tables.

Comment: Doesn't just closing the statement work? It should close all opened resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand.  Are you executing select statements within your procedure that you don't want returned?  Is it the rows affected that is being returned that is the result set you don't want?  If its the latter you can add SET NOCOUNT ON to the beginning of the procedure to keep the rows affected from being returned.

Comment: SELECT statements returned as result set. I am using CallableStatement statement = cx.prepareCall(ProcedureSQL)

Answer (score 0):

```
 statement.executeUpdate()
```

should execute your sql without returning a resultset.

Comment: currently I am using CallableStatement statement = cx.prepareCall(ProcedureSQL); will give a try with executeUpdate()

Comment: When trying with executeUpdate to run stored procedure it throws exception:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: INSERT/UPDATE cannot be executed, please retry.